# How to track cancel membership from Paypal

Tags: paypal, membership

I am using recurring membership payment from Paypal. I would like to know if any member cancel the membership from paypal manually, how can I get the return value/URL from the paypal, so that I can track the member cancel the membership from paypal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Instant Payment Notifications and PayPal will notify you almost instantly when a customer cancels their recurring payments profile within PayPal. That will allow you to track members cancelling their memberships.

Here is a link to the documentation on IPN:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Here is a link for how to create an IPN Listener:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/